# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

i got a problem with android studio .. my eclipse code is well imported in android studio but when i try to run it .. it runs on android 7 but not on others .. and when i try to build the apk file it's the same problem

this is the error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.class

this is the graddle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.getemplate.travelingbird"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In terminal execute in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

It helped me.